# binom.pmf only returning zero

Tags: python, scipy

code:

```
def expected_profit(n):
    total = 0
    X = np.arange(0,n+1)
    p = np.arange(0,n+1)
    profit = np.arange(0,n+1)
    for i in list(range(1,n+1)):
        print("X_i:", X[i])
        p[i] = binom.pmf(X[i],n,19/20)
        print(p[i])
        if X[i] > 100:
            profit[i] = 50*n-60*(X[i]-100)
        else:
            profit[i] = 50*n
        total += profit[i]*p[i]
    return total
expected_profit(10)
>>>0
```

For some reason, after each iteration, `p[i]` is equal to zero. Yet when I manually type out (for example) `binom.pmf(10,10,19/20)` I get a non zero answer. What is the problem here?

This seems to happen with any call to `binom.pmf` within the function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `p = np.arange(0,n+1)` you initialize `p` with an **integer** array `0,...,n`. That makes that `binom.pmf(...)` is converted to an integer when assigned to `p[i]`. The solution is to make `p` an array of floats.  `np.zeros()` by default creates an array of floats. The same problem holds for `profit`.

Fitting this into the code would look like:

```py
from scipy.stats import binom
import numpy as np

def expected_profit(n):
    n = 10
    total = 0
    X = np.arange(0, n + 1)
    p = np.zeros(n + 1, dtype=float)
    profit = np.zeros(n + 1, dtype=float)
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        p[i] = binom.pmf(X[i], n, 19/20)
        if X[i] > 100:
            profit[i] = 50 * n - 60 * (X[i] - 100)
        else:
            profit[i] = 50 * n
        total += profit[i] * p[i]
        
expected_profit(10)
```